# Is it possible to add to char type variable to get string ?

Tags: c++, string, char

Let's say I have 2 string variables

```
string str1 = "A";
string str2 = "B";
string str3;
```

Doing

```
str3 = str1 + str2;
```

Would get me

```
str3 = "AB"
```

My question is would it be possible to do addition in a somewhat similar fashion if instead of string type, str1 and str2, there would be char type values? If not, could anyone suggest me some smart workarounds if possible?

```
char str1 = 'A';
char str2 = 'B';
string str3; // <------ I need to get "AB" in str3 somehow
```

Thank you

Comment: See [std::string::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/)

Comment: `@Jokubas11` .. see more ways given below..

Answer (score 4):

Sure. There are several ways. Heres a few.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
      char str1 = 'A';
      char str2 = 'B';
      string str3;
       //using operator+=
       str3 += str1;
       str3 += str2;

       cout << str3 << endl;
       str3.clear();
       //using push_back
       str3.push_back(str1);
       str3.push_back(str2);

       cout << str3 << endl;
       str3.clear();
       //using array access
       str3.resize(2);
       str3[0] = str1;
       str3[1] = str2;
       cout << str3 << endl;

       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's entirely possible to concatenate `char` to a `std::string`, you just need one of the operands to be a `std::string`, otherwise you are essentially adding integers.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a = 'A';
    char b = 'B';

    std::string str = std::string() + a + b;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create the string in one go. This is the most efficient way also:

```
char a = 'A';
char b = 'B';

std::string str{a, b};

std::cout << str << std::endl; // "AB"
```

This uses the initializer_list constructor of `std::string`.

---

For a more general way of constructing a string (from any type that works with `basic_ostream::operator<<`) you can use `stringstream`:

```
char a = 'A';
char b = 'B';

std::stringstream ss;

ss << a << b;

std::string str2 = ss.str();

std::cout << str2 << std::endl; // "AB"
```

Comment: Most efficient, indeed. But perhaps not what the OP was asking for exactly.

Comment: @notanalien how so?

Comment: @notanalien "would it be possible to do addition in a somewhat **similar** fashion [...]? If not, could anyone suggest me some smart workarounds if possible?" how is this not what the OP was asking for? And even if the OP didn't ask for it, it's a good way to achieve this. Remember this site doesn't benefit the OP only.

Comment: My interpretation of "do addition in a somewhat similar fashion" was along the lines of "concatenate `std::string`s and `char`s using `operator+()`, but after re-reading the question I am not so certain. My mistake.

Comment: @notanalien the idea is indeed to concatenate chars into a string. That is the operation asked for. Now this can be achieved in C++ several ways. `std::string::operator+`, `std::string::push_back`, `std::ostream::operator<<` etc. The fact that the op was familiar with one way `std::string::operator+` doesn't mean we need to limit ourselves to just finding an `operator+`.

Answer (score -1):

There are following ways..

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define pb push_back

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a = 'A';
    char b = 'B';
    //using string class fill constructor    
    string str3;
    str3 = string(1,a) + string(1,b);
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    //using stringstream
    stringstream ss;
    ss << a << b;
    str3 = ss.str();
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    //using string push_back
    str3.pb(a);
    str3.pb(b);
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    //using string::operator+=
    str3+=a;
    str3+=b;
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    //using string::append
    str3.append(1,a);
    str3.append(1,b);
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    //using string::insert
    str3.insert(0,1,a);
    str3.insert(1,1,b);
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    //using string::replace
    str3.replace(0,1,1,a);
    str3.replace(1,1,1,b);
    cout << str3;
    str3.clear();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```